# Аргументом получаю массив, как его превратить в строку во Vue?

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js, список

```
<div class="v-main-box__area-bottom-right-info">
    <h2>{{movies_data.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{movies_data.year}}, {{movies_data.genres}}</p>
    <p>Режиссёр: {{movies_data.directors}}</p>
    <p>Актёры</p>
    <span>{{movies_data.description}}</span>
</div>[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Cортирую массив, в качестве одного из аргументов получаю массив и он у меня выводится с квадратными скобками и кавычками. Как мне убрать кавычки квадратные скобки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `movies_data.genres.join(', ')`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает!